# Compare values of two different DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrames, both have the same columns but one is for historic data and the other for 'new' data. New data may sometimes contain info that is already in historic data. So I want to say if the value of 'comment_id' in new data is already present in historic data, no nothing. Else, add that row to historic data.

I tried doing this:

```
historic_comments = [x for x in filtered_comments if filtered_comments['comment_id'] not in historic_comments['comment_id']]
```

But got error:

TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'

Comment: You can really only do this kind of approach if the comments are literally identical. Append `values`. You need also to properly index your `filtered_comments` at the start of the expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use boolean mask and [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html):

```
m = ~filtered_comments['comment_id'].isin(historic_comments['comment_id'])
out = pd.concat([historic_comments, filtered_comments[m]], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> out  # new historic_comments dataframe
  comment_id
0    bonjour
1      hello
2      world
3        new

>>> filtered_comments
  comment_id
0      hello
1        new
2      world

>>> historic_comments
  comment_id
0    bonjour
1      hello
2      world
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, your solution worked perfectly. I have a question, what does ~ do?

Comment: ~ is the "bitwise not" operator. True become False, False become True.

Comment: I have one last question, what does ignore_index=True acomplish in this case? I tried reading concat documentation but I can't quite understand its role in this case.

Comment: If you don't reset_index, the index will be 0,1,2,1 instead of 0,1,2,3

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you can do assuming `historic_df` is old df and `new_df` is new df

```
historic_df = pd.concat(
    [historic_df, new_df.loc[~new_df["comment_id"].isin(historic_df["comment_id"])]],
    ignore_index=True,
)
```

Comment: I try to find a difference between our answers :-)

Comment: I didn't see your answer before I posted I swear :)

Comment: Don't worry about that. Great minds feel alike :)